# Construction problem of hyperplane which is not contain each irreducible component of some proper closed subet of $\mathbb{P}^r$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective proper closed subset of $\mathbb{P}^r$. Is there a hyperplane which does not contain each irreducible conponent of $X$?

If base field is finie, is it also true? maybe if it is not true, I want to countexample...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course: choose a point on one of the irreducible components then take  any hyperplane not containing that point!  (This works also for a finite base field)

If the base field is infinite, you can choose one point on each irreducible component, take a hyperplane avoiding all those points and thus find a hyperplane which does not  contain **any** irreducible component of your subset.